# c# Trying to understand composition, but my wrapper objects are accessing the base class field rather than using the derived implementation

Tags: c#

```
public abstract class Beverage
{
    public string description = "Unknown Beverage";
    public string GetDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
}

public abstract class CondimentDecorator : Beverage
{
    public abstract new string GetDescription();
}


public class Espresso : Beverage 
{
    public Espresso()
    {
        description = "Espresso";
    }

class Mocha : CondimentDecorator
{

    Beverage beverage;

    public Mocha(Beverage beverage)
    {
        this.beverage = beverage;
    }
    public override string GetDescription()
    {
        return beverage.GetDescription() + ", Mocha";
    }
```

Espresso is intended to be the component, and Mocha is intended to be the wrapper. 
Now when I instantiate without using composition the code executes as expected and returns the description: Espresso:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Beverage beverage = new Espresso();
        Console.WriteLine(beverage.GetDescription());

 Output: Espresso
```

However, when I use composition, the beverage description field from the Beverage base class is accessed and the program returns the description "Unknown Beverage." However, I'm expecting the output: "Espresso, Mocha"

```
 Beverage beverage2 = new Espresso();

        beverage2 = new Mocha(beverage2);

        Console.WriteLine(beverage2.GetDescription());
```

Comment: why are you using the `new` keyword in the abstract method declaration?

Comment: also, you can't override a method in C# unless it's either `virtual` or `abstract`. `Beverage.GetDescription()` is neither.

Comment: I can't find the post that explains it more clearly, but I think it has to do with you selecting the `Beverage` type on the left side, so calling `beverage2.GetDescription()` just calls the base classes method. You likely have to cast it, `Console.WriteLine(((Mocha)beverage2).GetDescription());`

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `GetDescription` method in `Beverage` isn't virtual.  When you write `beverage.GetDescription()`, the compiler looks and sees that the type of `beverage` is `Beverage` and then sees that it has a non-virtual `GetDescription` method.  Since it's not virtual, the derived `GetDescription` isn't called.

What you want is something more like this:

```
public abstract class Beverage
{
    public string description = "Unknown Beverage";
    public virtual string GetDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
}

public abstract class CondimentDecorator : Beverage
{
    public override string GetDescription()
    {
        return GetDescriptionOverride();
    }

    protected abstract string GetDescriptionOverride();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever a class defines a virtual function (or method), most compilers add a hidden member variable to the class which points to an array of pointers to (virtual) functions called the virtual method table (VMT or Vtable). These pointers are used at runtime to invoke the appropriate function implementations, because at compile time it may not yet be known if the base function is to be called or a derived one implemented by a class that inherits from the base class.
>   [Virtual method table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)

@kai pointed out the problem. The method need to be defined as virtual. Then the runtime knows to lookup an override method for runtime type which is Moccha in this case. Also if CondimentDecorator is abstract, there is no need to re-define CondimentDecorator again.

```
public abstract class Beverage
{
    public string description = "Unknown Beverage";
    public virtual string GetDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
}

public abstract class CondimentDecorator : Beverage
{

}

//no change to the rest
...
```

Do this and you will see output

```
"Espresso, Mocha"
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following line you are hiding the GetDescription method on the base class

```
public abstract new string GetDescription();
```

In the second example, where you see the problem, you are typing the variable as Beverage.  Therefore you end up calling the method on the base class.

As a simple example:

```
public class First
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "First";
    }
}

public class Second : First
{
    public new string GetName()
    {
        return "Second";
    }
}

public static class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Second second = new Second();
        Console.WriteLine(second.GetName());
        // Prints "Second"

        First first = second;
        Console.WriteLine(first.GetName());
        // Prints "First"

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Then try the following change:

```
public class First
{
    public virtual string GetName()
    {
        return "First";
    }
}

public class Second : First
{
    public override string GetName()
    {
        return "Second";
    }
}
```

You will find it prints Second both times.

Comment: Thank you Karle, Kai and Awakening Byte, all answers very helpful. And your example was especially helpful Karle, thanks!